Reduce AWS Load Balancer health check delay
When I make a deployment to my Fargate service, the new containers experience a strange 3 minute delay when registered with the Network Load Balancer. The new HTTP Targets are taking exactly 3 minutes to go from Init to Healthy, even though the URL the health check calls becomes operational before the 3 minutes begin, as verified using the container's public IP.
I changed the health check parameters from defaults to allowed minimums, but this delay didn't change at all.
Is there a way to remove or lessen this wait?
